# Website dedicated to UNanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, unanswered-questions

Why don't you guys create a website where the **unanswered** questions (sorted by oldest) from the stack networks are displayed, giving them a second line of exposure?

I, as an user of the Stack Exchange network, like to have more than 90% questions answered.

I would also suggest that you start interacting and getting users involved more. After all, loyal users are what make a website or an idea successful.

Comment: Hmm... you mean like `http://[sitename].com/unanswered`?

Comment: Here's a chair, son. Have a seat. Let's talk about your problems, shall we?

Comment: Do you think someone will go to a site with only unanswered questions? The ones who want to answer these are already able to do so via the unanswered-tab.

Answer (score 14):

You can find a list of unanswered questions already built into Stack Overflow and given prominent mention in main navigation under *Unanswered*.

To get the exact view you're looking for, just click *Newest* and *voila*: [7535 pages of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=7535&tab=newest)—sorted by date—there for the taking.

Now, I hear you asking: "why are there so many pages of unanswered questions?" Well, unanswered questions are unanswered usually for one of two good reasons:

- They're not very good questions to begin with, or
- They require specialized knowledge that even the vast user base of Stack Overflow can't answer

Making a separate site or making the already-prominent *Unanswered* section more prominent doesn't make these reasons go away. So while it's a bit sad that some questions don't get the love, it's a bit of an intractable problem that isn't solved by quick fixes.